# how to add wirinigPi library on buildroot?

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, buildroot, wiringpi

How to add wiringpi in Buildroot image ?

I followed the same steps as described here: How to add an out-of-tree package to buildroot? The download of the git archive functions correctly but the compilation of the library doesn't work. I tried to change the "sh build" command in the .mk file using an absolute path to where the archive was extracted (in output/build).

I also tried to change the build.sh included in WiringPi archive with absolute paths everytime cd was used beacause the make command used with buildroot wasn't executed in the same directory Can you help me write a correct .mk file that will compile wiringpi for my buildroot image using this git: https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiringPi is/was already in buildroot packages, however, the whole library was [deprecated by the author](https://web.archive.org/web/20220405225008/wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/) at some point. Due to this and apparently also because the WiringPi's author deleted all sources ([according to this](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/commit/90dd7803914ec2d817e39b20bc88f09b0f04f54f)), it was moved to buildroot's [legacy packages](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/7763ba7007172ceb5e928ae5902735d727aaa90d/Config.in.legacy). However, that deprecation post is now removed by the WiringPi author (which is why the first link points to internet archives), so it could be that the sources are also restored and the WiringPi package from the legacy config works or could be made working with small modifications.

TLDR; Even if you *could* get it working, you *should* use something else.